Missing `convert_endianness` in module `solana_program::alt_bn128::compression::prelude`
I am attempting to utilize altbn254 syscalls with Solana (1.17.14), but cannot compile due to an unresolved import of convert_endianness.
This is my cargo.toml
[package]
name = "program"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
ahash = "=0.8.6"
ark-bn254 = "0.4.0"
ark-ec = "0.4.2"
ark-ff = "0.4.2"
ark-serialize = "0.4.2"
solana-program = "=1.17.14"

[dev-dependencies]
ark-std = "0.4.0"
array-bytes = "6.2.2"
serde = "1.0.195"
serde_json = "1.0.111"

[lib]
crate-type = ["cdylib", "lib"]


In lib.rs:
...
use solana_program::alt_bn128::compression::prelude::convert_endianness;
...

Compiling with cargo build-bpf yields:
error[E0432]: unresolved import `solana_program::alt_bn128::compression::prelude::convert_endianness`
 --> src/lib.rs:5:5
  |
5 | use solana_program::alt_bn128::compression::prelude::convert_endianness;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ no `convert_endianness` in `alt_bn128::compression::prelude`

However, the function does exist and should be available for use:
https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.17.14/solana_program/alt_bn128/compression/prelude/fn.convert_endianness.html
Am I missing something in my Cargo.toml? How can I proceed?

It looks like the convert_endianness function isn't available in on-chain programs. If you look at the source code, all usage is gated with #[cfg(not(target_os = "solana"))], like here https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.17.14/src/solana_program/alt_bn128/compression.rs.html#65
You'll need to use functions that are available in the #[cfg(target_os = "solana")] section at https://docs.rs/solana-program/1.17.14/src/solana_program/alt_bn128/compression.rs.html#186
